# Display changed elements in XSLT output in bold

Tags: .net, xslt

I'm working on a piece of software that develops flight plans for aircraft operators.  The aircraft has a sensor that can have various settings adjusted, and these settings are split by way of what we call "segments" of the flight plan.  (A segment is some certain amount of time in the plan, and sensor settings only change when moving between segments.)

The flight plan is output as an HTML file, which is generated from an XSL transform of a serialized XML object, via XslCompiledTransform in C# .NET.  Its structure is very consistent, since there are a limited number of settings to adjust.  For each segment, a pair of tables is output, delimited by `<hr />` tags.

What I'd like to be able to do is take that output and, each time a setting changes from segment to segment, bold that setting's text in the final output by wrapping it in `<b>` tags.  A (paraphrased) example: (**EDITED for clarification**)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Setting 1</td><td>a</td>
    <td>Setting 2</td><td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Setting 3</td><td>c</td>
    </tr>
<table>

<hr />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Setting 1</td><td>a</td>
    <td>Setting 2</td><td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Setting 3</td><td>c</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Given that output from the XSL transform, I'd like to wrap c in a  or  tag to bold it, resulting in something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Setting 1</td><td>a</td>
    <td>Setting 2</td><td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Setting 3</td><td>c</td>
    </tr>
<table>

<hr />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Setting 1</td><td>a</td>
    <td>Setting 2</td><td><b>d</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Setting 3</td><td>c</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I'm not sure whether to write a helper object in .net, use a utility, run the output through a separate XSL transform, or what.  **What would be the best method to go about it given the tools I have at hand?**

Comment: Are you asking for an XSLT transformation to convert the output of the first transformation to the new desired format? If so, could you provide a minimal but well-formed XML document that is the output of the first transformation and should be the input of the wanted transformation?

Comment: I edited my example for clarity (to show matched pairs of tables with the hr I mentioned).  I don't want to upload the real HTML I'm putting together since it's a proprietary government project; I'm sure you understand.  :)

Comment: Why can't you just once provide a *well-formed* XML?

Comment: Not so clear with  your requirement.. probably you are missing key rules ..

Answer (score 1):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "table[preceding-sibling::table[2]]
    /tr
      /td[position() mod 2 = 0]
 ">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vPrevTableTD" select=
   "../../preceding-sibling::table[2]
                 /tr/td[position() = $vPos]"/>

  <td>
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not(. = $vPrevTableTD)">
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one after making it well-formed XML document):

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Setting 1</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>Setting 2</td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Setting 3</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Setting 1</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>Setting 2</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Setting 3</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Setting 1</td>
         <td>a</td>
         <td>Setting 2</td>
         <td>b</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Setting 3</td>
         <td>c</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <hr>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Setting 1</td>
         <td>a</td>
         <td>Setting 2</td>
         <td><b>d</b></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Setting 3</td>
         <td>c</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: My example wasn't quite clear, and as a result I'm not having much success with this stylesheet.  Sorry about that.  I updated the example for clarity.

Comment: @JimDagg: I have edited the answer. It now processes your latest XML document format and produces the wanted result.